# Getting EC2 instance id on a webpage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to host a simple webpage on my EC2 instance which shows "This webpage is served from the instance: [instance-id]". I want to output the instance id there. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is your server side programming language experience - i.e. PHP, Java, etc?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Congratulations on your first post. What have you tried? Add your code and any errors/output to your question and that will help others find solutions to your problem. It may be helpful to you to read: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can get your instance ID by using simply curl:

`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`

And then display by your application. The IP address `169.254.169.254` is a link-local address and is valid only from the instance, it works for every EC2 instance.